# Can Shillelagh be used to help other people?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Can I cast Shillelagh on a weapon and then hand it to a fellow party member to use with the Shillelagh benefits?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## No

The spell is very specific that:

> The spell ends if you cast it again or if you let go of the weapon.

Once you give it to someone else, you have to let it go. Thus ending the spell.